# TS Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent with Material-UI and @react-three/fiber

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, material-ui, react-three-fiber

I create a Next.js application that use Material-UI and @react-three/fiber library.

I recently pass Material-UI to V5 and a error is appear.

Here is the error:
[image: error]

I search everything to remove it but I found nothing.

So I try to create a new project with Material-UI V5 and I install other dependency one by one. In the begin the error is not show but when I install `@react-three/fiber` AND `@react-three/drei` the error appear.

So I found that a `Box` component is exported from `@material-ui` and `@react-three/drei` so I understand now the error.

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^7.0.6",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.16",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

But I don't found how to fix it...

Someone have idee?

Comment: 1. either React Three Fiber fix the type declaration; or typescript allow more union type;  -- https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/1752#discussioncomment-6282948

Comment: \[^\] 1. if you are going to do this in a dirty way, then 1a. `<Box component="div">...</Box>` didnt work 1b. `Delete all of these definition files: node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/` / `interface IntrinsicElements extends Pick<ThreeElements, 'ambientLight'> {` didnt work (maybe I still put too much prop) / too dirty 1c. **wrap all `Box` to a single entry** -- `export const BoxGn = React.forwardRef((props: React.ComponentProps<typeof Box>, ref: React.ComponentRef<typeof Box>) => {   // @ts-ignore   return <Box {...props} ref={ref} />; });` -- did work, less dirty for me (dk proper or not)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Solution 1

The stable version of MaterialUI fix this problem.

Use this package:

```sh
npm install @mui/material
```

#### Solution 2 by [Vivere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14183155/vivere)

Add the `component` props to a `div` to avoid TypeScript error.

```
<Box component="div">...</Box>
```

Comment: I ran into this error too. I understand that both `@mui/material` and the three libraries export a `Box`, but why should this error appear?

Comment: I think it's maybe bcs types definitions in @material-ui/core v.5 is not correctly defined and enter in conflict with @three.js definition. And when you import both, typescript doesn't know which types is correct. Did you try with `@mui/material` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of `@mui/material`. I see that for you that fixed it but in my case the issue is still persisting.

Comment: It's the same error? When you remove `drei` package the error is no longer here?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. I tested and removed the `drei` and the error goes away.

Comment: Can you share a simple codesandbox to compare with my own codebase? I try now to import Box from mui and Box from three and the error doesn't appear

Comment: I don't have a single clue. On my local pc, it is working, on the remote one, it is not. I create a code sandbox, there it is working as well. I even reinstalled node, deleted the cache, removed node_modules & package JSON and the error still persists. Could you maybe share your `package.json` versions?

Comment: Ok, I found a way to reproduce it. Apparently, I need to also write some three code, and if the components are at the same level, then the error appears

Comment: Ok nice. You're on the good way! Here is my package.json: https://gist.github.com/Melvynx/f1b1402411d1d7ef1d47c58d90cebfac

Comment: So I managed to solve it by writing the component type of the box: `<Box component="div" ...` This is pretty strange, but it works for now. I filed to both `mui` and `fiber` GitHub pages an issue. Hope that I will get some kind of guidance that makes me understand this behaviour.

Comment: After hours of looking, looking again, scratching my head, renaming modules, reading webpack docs, reading typescript articles, github issue logs, code-splitting, ad nauseum,  @Vivere your last note fixed this ... thank you! ... I should note, this is also an issue using Babylon ... This will do for now, but there HAS to be a better fix than this ...

Comment: I have added your comment in my answer @Vivere

Comment: Right, so I am on `5.3.3` and this is the only thing that worked. Dirty and not OK but it works. So frustrating - I've spent hours on this trying all the other approaches.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error because of importing `@react-three/drei`. I have successfully localized files, which cause the error to appear, but i'm unable to determine the root cause. I would appreciate all input from more TypeScript-savvy people out there.

This is a rather ugly workaround. **Delete** all of these definition files:

- `node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/`

  - `MeshWobbleMaterial.d.ts`
  - `MeshDistortMaterial.d.ts`
  - `PointMaterial.d.ts` (<- for newer versions)

Of course now you can't use these Components in a Typescript context now.

You can **share** and **pin** these changes by using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). This will setup a **post install** step, that will apply the changes (deleted files) after running `npm/yarn install`.

Comment: Thanks, but if you redo a `npm install` the deleted modules will be here again?

Comment: This will be solved by `patch-package`. When you put `"postinstall": "patch-package"` to your package.json,  after downloading packages during `npm install`, this script will delete the .d-files if present. Please look into the discription of patch-package, or ask me, when you need help!

Comment: THIS WORKED !!! this is so bad !!

Comment: Can you share the process you used to localize the conflicting files?

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding `patch-package`. I used it to remove the real cause of the issue - the cavalier global extension of `JSX.IntrinsicElements` by the library, which causes heavily templated/inferred components such as `Box` to grow too big. See [my note on GitHub](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/1752#discussioncomment-6282948).

Comment: I prefer this approach because it allows me to control the issue at the source, instead of arbitrarily changing my own code to work around it. Except I had to remove the `declare global { ... interface IntrinsicElements { ... } }` block in **node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/three-types.d.ts**. I then used patch-package (`npm i -D patch-package`) to source-control the change to node_modules.

Answer (score 6):

### If you're using VS Code

---

#### This worked for me (TLDR)

1. create a `.vscode` directory and add the `settings.json` file.
2. Add this configuration

   ```
   {
     "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true
   }
   ```

---

#### Context

if you're using vs code and seeing this error. This was because of an inconsistent typescript version between what vscode internally uses to provide ts-related features and the typescript versions you're using in your app.

I tried this option

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74847054/13822685

but could not follow since the latest version of VS Code does not show the option to switch TS version to the workspace version in case you've never enabled this before. Below are the version details.

```
Version: 1.74.2 (user setup)
Commit: e8a3071ea4344d9d48ef8a4df2c097372b0c5161
Date: 2022-12-20T10:29:14.590Z
Electron: 19.1.8
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: No
```

---

So `typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk` will force the vscode to use the typescript version of the current workspace that is likely to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm using VSCode and selecting the workspace typescript version solved the issue.
(press F1 -> Typscript: Select Typescript Version)

Comment: yes, it does solve the issue. But the problem in my case was; I was not even seeing the option `Select Typescript Version` in the command palette.
After these configurations, I started seeing the option to select `Current Workspace Version` option.

Comment: Given your fix, it's likely that the bug is present only in certain versions of TS. What version are you using? :)

Comment: From the other post, you're using 4.7.4, but I still have the issue in 4.7.4

Comment: Still facing this issue. Can't even set current workspace version even after restarting VSCode after adding the field to settings.json

Comment: @Leafyshark are you seeing the option to switch to the current workspace version in your command pellete?

Comment: @abdadeel even after adding typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk: true to my settings.json, I do not see it. Only in the particular project I am seeing the error  "expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent" - other projects without the error I am able to "use workspace version"

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by adding this to `tsconfig.json`.

```
"jsx": "react",
"lib": ["ES5", "ES2015", "ES2016", "DOM", "ES2015.Promise"],
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

Answer (score -2):

I've encountered this same issue with `@react-three/fiber` and `chakra-ui`

This is what worked for me. Cast the props as `any`. This may be a hacky way to do things but it does clear out the warning.

see sample code here:

```
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { Link as CharkaLink, LinkProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';

export interface ICustomLinkProps extends LinkProps {
  href: string;
  external?: boolean;
}

const CustomLink = (props: ICustomLinkProps) => {
  const { href, children, color = 'teal.500' } = props;
  
// typecast to any to prevent issues with props from three/drei or three/fiber
  const propsAny = props as any;
  return (
    <NextLink href={href} passHref legacyBehavior>
      <CharkaLink color={color} {...propsAny}>
        {children}
      </CharkaLink>
    </NextLink>
  );
};

export default CustomLink;
```

Comment: `any` is never a solution :/ I prefer keep typescript working. But thanks you !