# Typescript Box produces a union type that is too complex to represent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, material-ui, react-typescript

Rendering a `Box` produces the following error:

> Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts(2590)

As I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692230/ts-expression-produces-a-union-type-that-is-too-complex-to-represent-with-materi), this is due to having both `@mui/material` and `@react-three/drei` & `@react-three/fiber` installed.

What is the reasoning behind this error? I'm only importing the `Box` component from `mui`. Is there a type mixup or something? What would be the solution/workaround?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Setup a cra app: `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`
2. Add the following packages to your `package.json`

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.18.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.1.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.51",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.4",
    "@mui/system": "^5.0.4",
    "@react-three/drei": "^7.16.8",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^7.0.17",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "three": "^0.133.1",
    "three-stdlib": "^2.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "zustand": "^3.5.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.33",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/three": "^0.133.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^14.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "jest-when": "^3.4.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
```

3. Run `npm install`
4. Make sure you're running on `Typescript v4.4.4`
5. Add the following component to your `src`. I name it `ThreeRenderer.tsx`:

```js
import { Html, OrbitControls, PerspectiveCamera, useGLTF, useProgress } from '@react-three/drei';
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { FC, Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { AnimationAction, AnimationMixer } from 'three';
import { GLTF, GLTFLoader } from 'three-stdlib';
import create from 'zustand';
import { devtools } from 'zustand/middleware';

export const useGLTFModel = create<{ readonly model: () => GLTF | undefined }>(
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  devtools((set) => ({
    model: () => undefined
  }))
);

export const useGLTFAnimationAction = create<{ readonly animationAction: () => AnimationAction[] | undefined }>(
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  devtools((set) => ({
    animationAction: () => undefined
  }))
);

interface ModelProps {
  readonly gltfPath: string;
  readonly onLoad: () => void;
}

const Model: FC<ModelProps> = ({ gltfPath, onLoad }) => {
  const model = useGLTF(gltfPath, undefined, undefined, (loader: GLTFLoader) => {
    loader.manager.onLoad = onLoad;
  });

  // Refs
  const rootRef = useRef();
  const animationActionsRef = useRef<AnimationAction[]>();

  // Mixer
  const [mixer] = useState(() => new AnimationMixer(model.scene));
  useFrame((_state, delta) => mixer.update(delta));

  // Effects
  useEffect(() => {
    useGLTFModel.setState({ model: () => model });

    animationActionsRef.current = model.animations.map((animation) => mixer.clipAction(animation, rootRef.current));
    useGLTFAnimationAction.setState({ animationAction: () => animationActionsRef.current });

    return () => {
      model.animations.map((animation) => mixer.uncacheClip(animation));
    };
  }, [model, mixer]);

  return <primitive ref={rootRef.current} object={model.scene} />;
};

const Progress = () => {
  const { progress } = useProgress();
  return (
    <Html center>
      <span style={{ color: 'white' }}>{progress}% loaded</span>
    </Html>
  );
};

const ThreeRenderer: FC<ModelProps> = ({ gltfPath, onLoad }): JSX.Element => {
  const cameraRef = useRef();

  return (
    <Canvas>
      <PerspectiveCamera ref={cameraRef} position={[0, 5, 5]} />
      <OrbitControls camera={cameraRef.current} />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <Suspense fallback={<Progress />}>
        {/* <Environment preset="city" /> */}
        <Model gltfPath={gltfPath} onLoad={onLoad} />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ThreeRenderer;
```

6. Go to `App.tsx` and add a `Box` component from `@mui/material`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Box} from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <Box>

        </Box>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

7. You should see the error appear. What I see:
   [image]

**NOTE**
Please try to reproduce this error locally in `VSCode` or your preferred editor. I did not manage to reproduce this on `codesandbox` for example. I don't know why there the issue does not appear. I suspect that's because they use a different typescript version.

**UPDATE**

I've opened issues on both MUI and react-three:

- [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/1752#discussion-3635926)
- [mui](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29176#issue-1031045251)

Comment: Can you add your code here?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I added the packages as well as a picture.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-material-demo-forked-9tl5q?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: I don't understand, then what's going on in my local sandbox.

Comment: Check if your project uses workspace's typescript version.

Comment: @zilijonas I'm using vscode and I configured it to use the version from my node modules, the error still shows up.

Comment: I found it, so after I install `@react-three/fiber` then it breaks

Comment: @Vivere wasn't it mentioned in the original question you linked? but I suppose you need that package.

Comment: Yup, I need it. I created an issue on their GitHub page and I hope I get some guidance. It is really really strange and I don't have any leads on why this is occuring.

Comment: @NearHuscarl I finally managed to reproduce it on two different PCs in multiple sandboxes. But I did not manage to reproduce it in `codesandbox.io`. Can you look at the updated post and let me know if this issue appears on your side as well?

Comment: [codsandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxcomponent-material-demo-forked-ot73s?file=/demo.tsx). Sorry, I don't have time to install and test on local. You should file an issue on MUI repo, someone on there probably can help you.

Comment: I did, for both `mui` and `fiber` repos. Hopefully they will help me with some workarounds.

Comment: Maybe this is related to typescript because 4.4.4 was just released recently? Try downgrading it to see if it helps.

Comment: @Vivere did you ever get to the bottom of this? I've been trying different things for hours. Like you, I was using `@react-three/fiber` and uninstalling fixes the error but I need R3F.

Comment: @ChrisCrossCrash adding a `component="div"` to Box fixes it. See my latest update where I posted links to issues opened against both repositories. Follow those links for more info on the matter.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open a JavaScript or TypeScript file in VS Code.
2. In the VS Code command palette, run the TypeScript: `Select  TypeScript version command`.
3. Make sure you have Use workspace version selected.

Post Credits: [FreePhoenix888](https://github.com/FreePhoenix888).

Original Answer: [Here](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/3714#issuecomment-1357167913)

Answer (score 4):

While I'm sure there are several situations where this problem can occur, the reason why this was happening to me right now was that `npm` was, installing a duplicated version of `@chakra-ui/system` which defines the type declartion of `forwardRef()`.

When I ran `npm ls @chakra-ui/system` I could see that I had both `@chakra-ui/system@1.9.1` and `@chakra-ui/system@1.9.0`.

This is likely because some dependencies, like [`@chakra-ui/skeleton@1.2.4`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@chakra-ui/skeleton@1.2.4/package.json) defines an exact version `1.9.0` of `@chakra-ui/system`, while most packages, like [`@chakra-ui/menu@1.8.3`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@chakra-ui/menu@1.8.3/package.json), defines a very open `>=1.0.0` as a `peerDependencies`. Since [npm v7](https://github.blog/2020-10-13-presenting-v7-0-0-of-the-npm-cli/), npm installs `peerDependencies` by default.

It seems like this can result in npm installing the *latest* version for the open `>=1.0.0` and then the specific `1.9.0` separately and not be intelligent enough to dedupe it.

I could work around this by either

- `rm package-lock.json && npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. This has a lot of affects on what packages npm installs however.
- or, add an `overrides` (requires `npm >=8.3`)to the `package.json` to specify a specific version to install.

  ```json
  "overrides": {
       "@chakra-ui/system": "1.9.1"
   }
  ```

  You might have to regenerate the `package-lock.json` by deleting it before running install again to actually force this new resolution.

  This will *only* make sure to dedupe the specific package and not change other, unrelated packages like ´--legacy-peer-deps` does.

Answer (score -1):

The error can be reproduced using `next@14` with `typescript@5` and the following dependencies:

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.9",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.96.5",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.15.15",
    "three": "^0.160.1",
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/1752), `@react-three/fiber` is extending the global definition of the component `Box`; both `mui` and `@react-three/fiber` expose a `Box` component, but the latter makes its types globally available causing the reported error.

As of February 2024 there's no perfect solution that does not imply downgrading dependencies.

As a maintainable workaround, you can create a global mui `Box` replacement specifying its `component` value, such as:

```
import { BoxProps, Box as MuiBox } from '@mui/material';

type Props = Omit<BoxProps, 'component'>;

export const Box = (props: Props) => <MuiBox component={'div'} {...props} />;
```

You may also name the re-exported `Box` `Div` to make everything more syntactically accurate.

Note that the same error has also been reported for Chakra's `Box` version, so this solution might apply to those using it instead of Mui.