# How to fix "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)"?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use Button from `@chakra-ui/react` npm library but the Button element produces this error:

> TypeScript: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)
> Example:

```
import {Button} from "@chakra-ui/react"

function Page() {
  return <Button onClick={(event) => {}}>Text</Button>
}
```

Answer (score 300, accepted):

## VSCode Typescript Extension

Make sure you are using the right typescript version.
Typescript extension can use its own version instead of using your project's typescript version which is set in package.json

### Solutions

#### GUI Solution

1. Open a JavaScript or TypeScript file in VS Code.
2. In the VS Code command palette (F1 or Ctrl+P is the shortcut by default), run the TypeScript: Select TypeScript version command.
3. Make sure you have `Use workspace version` selected

If there is no `Use workspace version` option
Make sure you have `typescript` in your dependencies in `package.json` and you have installed your dependencies by using `npm install` or `npm clean-install`
If you still do not have it - add `typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk: true` to `.vscode/settings.json` or find setting `Enable Prompt Use Workspace Tsdk` and enable it

#### JSON Solution

Update your vscode config at `./.vscode/settings.json` (create it if you do not have it)

```json
{
  "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

### Recomendation

**Setup typescript extension to prompt you whether to use workspace version**
Find setting 'Typescript: Enable Prompt Use Workspace Tsdk' in VsCode settings and enable it
[image]
In the next time you open your workspace in VsCode you will see this notification:
[image]
You want to click "Allow" :)

## Other Possible Solutions

1. Update npm version
   If you use nvm - `nvm install --latest-npm`
2. Update nodejs version
   If you are unable to update nodejs at the moment to the latest version you can update it to atlest the latest minor+path version (`x.latest.latest`) to not have breaking changes
3. Remove `node_modules` and `npm install`
4. if you have project separated by folders and it is situated inside of those, you are unable to select typescript version in vscode. In that case open new vscode and go directly into your folder with package.json. (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246617/pavol-travnik)

Comment: In my case, I was not able to see `Use workspace version` option in my editor. Then this solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/74940837/13822685

Comment: @abdadeel, do you have installed typescript npm package in your npm package?

Comment: yes I have. `typescript: 4.7.4`

Comment: @abdadeel. It is interesting. VSCode must see it if you have typescript installed in your node_modules

Comment: it picked it up after I added `typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk: true` in `.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: I have personnaly the error with TS 4.7.4, I don't know understand why this fix would work.

Comment: This worked for me in the 3rd steps everything went back to normal. thanks

Comment: `enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk` did not work for me, I had to add `typescript.tsdk: "path/to/node_modules/typescript/lib"` as well, probably since `node_modules` wasn't in the root of the project.

Comment: excellent, but this works only if the package.json is in top level in vscode - if you have project separated by folders and it is situated inside of those, you are unable to select typescript version in vscode. In that case open new vscode and go directly into your folder with package.json

Comment: @PavolTravnik, thank you! I have added your words to my answer and marked that you are the author

Comment: related: [How do I force Visual Studio Code to always use my workspace's version of TypeScript for all projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74642723/11107541)

Comment: Finally did this and I still have the same issue. Also, Vercel build is failing, so I am not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 18):

Myself also faced same issue on using **chakra-ui** components in **next js 13**.

The next js version **13** was coming with typescript version **5.0.2**.
I have changed the typescript version to 4.9.5 on `package.json` file and reinstalled the npm packages after deleting `package-lock.json` file. This issue got solved and I tested with typescript compiler command

```
npx tsc --noEmit
```

Comment: Likely because VS Code was still using v4.9.5 and the workspace was v5.0.2.

Comment: It was not only in VS Code but also when I run eslint (lint checker) from command line.

Comment: oh my word, that was annoying to solve. this really helped thanks. For some reason, the error just appeared out of nowhere (thinking back it was after I added a new package to package.json), so deleting package-lock and reinstalling was the solution for me

Answer (score 11):

changing version of typescript to "typescript": "^4.9.5" in package.json and running yarn/npm install helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: Downgrading Typescript to 4.9.5 and selecting `Use workspace version` afterwards fixed it for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Go to the bottom bar in VSCode and pick the version of TS that match your package.json :

[vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htaqf.png)

It will be better if the TS version being used by vscode is higher than the current namespace version (in your project)

Answer (score 8):

I believe the issue is related to the NX env setup. I guess you've chosen the "emotion" option when setting up the NX app (I did the same as well).

I can confirm that the issue has been resolved by removing `"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"` from `tsconfig.json`. No extra steps needed.

Using `"typescript": "5.0.4"` and `"@chakra-ui/react": "2.6.0"`. All good.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Settings in VSCode and search for `'TypeScript version'` tick `'Typescript: Enable Prompt Use Workspace Tsdk'`

[image: A screenshot of the VSCode settings page with the above option selected.]

You'll get a prompt, click use workspace version.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue, but i am solved by to config

```
{
  "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

into ./.vscode/settings.json

Comment: It is the same what is my answer but by setting vscode config by changing json directly

Answer (score 3):

My issue was solved by changing the tsconfig.json file. 
I removed `"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that doesn't work the accepted solution try to delete the `node_modules` folder in your project and run again `npm install` or `yarn install`

Running both commands was triggering the issue for me.

Also you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348340/6826260) for `@mui/material` relative error

Answer (score 2):

After trying almost everything available here with no success, removing
this line from my `tsconfig.json` worked for me:

```
"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
```

It should be noted that this was done just after trying [@FreePhoenix888](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74847054/3546764) answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me I face the same issue. the chakra-ui version is 2.5.3 typescript version is 5.0.2. now Going back to typescript@4.9.5 this error getting solved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJgrf.png)
and last you should set user workspace typescript version,if your system is windows, snippt is ctrl + shift + p,choose your version, and reopen the tab, the error will disappear
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym13p.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChTGS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add this into "./.vscode/settings.json":

```
{
  "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
  "typescript.tsdk": "absolute_path_to/node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

**Note: typescript.tsdk use "absolute path" (not relative path), if not, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I realized that the TypeScript type inference was struggling with the complexity of thecomponent's types. To resolve this, I added the css="" prop to the Checkbox component. This seemed to help TypeScript better understand the type and eliminate the error.

```js
import { Checkbox } from '@chakra-ui/react';

// ...

<Checkbox
  colorScheme="red"
  defaultChecked
  aria-label="Checkbox"
  css=""  // Adding this prop resolved the error
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me without downgrading the TS version

Solved upgrading @chakra-ui/react from 2.5.2 to 2.5.5

Solved source - https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/7526#issuecomment-1493396539

Answer (score -1):

I correct the error by having this in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@/lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "components/Profile.jsx",
    "pages/profile.js",
    "pages/index.jsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts(2590)".

With Bootstrap and Material-UI components.

I tried everything that was mentioned here and there. For example, selecting the Workspace version of TS to use in VSC, downgrading my 5.x.x TS to v4.x.x, and so on.

I removed `"strict": true' from the compilerOptions section in tsconfig.json, and it fixed the problem for Material-UI, but not for Bootstrap.