# TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent

Tags: typescript

I am using [typescript-vim](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim)

I have TypeScript installed globally `npm install -g typescript`

My project's `package.json` shows `"typescript": "^5.1.6"`

If I run `:!tsc --version` in vim, `5.1.16` is shown.

- [How to fix "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74847053/how-to-fix-expression-produces-a-union-type-that-is-too-complex-to-represent-t)
- [chakra-ui/chakra-ui#3714](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/3714) and
- [TS Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent with Material-UI and @react-three/fiber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692230/ts-expression-produces-a-union-type-that-is-too-complex-to-represent-with-materi)

all point in the direction of discrepancies between the TS version in the project and the TS version being used by the compiler.

I believe that I have addressed any TypeScript versioning issues.  Are there other reasons for the `Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent` error?  Does anyone know what it means?

(Note: Error does not show up when viewing the project in VS Code.)

Here is a bit of the code:

```
        const apiParams = {...a, ...queryArgs} as any;
        apiQuery(apiParams, postData)  // <----------------- error is here
            .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
```